# Laravel resource controller won't recognize PUT route

Tags: php, laravel, controller, resources

I have a resource controller with method:

```
public function update(StoreRoleRequest $request, string $role)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $entry = Role::find($role);
    if ($entry) {
        $entry->name = $validated['name'];
        $entry->save();
        return new RoleResource($entry);
    }
    return response()->json(['result' => 'role not found, no data updated']);
}
```

My `api.php` contains:

```
Route::apiResource('roles', RoleController::class);
```

My routes are:

```
GET|HEAD        api/v1/roles/{role} ................................roles.show › Api\V1\RoleController@show
PUT|PATCH       api/v1/roles/{role} ................................... roles.update › Api\V1\RoleController@updat
DELETE          api/v1/roles/{role} ................................. roles.destroy › Api\V1\RoleController@destroy
```

When I send  PUT http://localhost/my_api/public/api/v1/roles/1:

code works OK

But when I send  PUT http://localhost/my_api/public/api/v1/roles/foo:

I get this message:

> "The PUT method is not supported for route api/v1/roles/foo. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.", "exception":

I tried updates of an existing entry in DB table roles with number as param and it correctly reports 'entry' not found.

Comment: you can use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) to prevent strings on ids

Comment: I suspect the problem is due to request validation. You could try to validate without using validated and in case of error return a response via json or just abort the function execution

Comment: Most likely there is a number constraint on the PUT route, which means `/foo` won't match. If you want to pass a string/slug, then don't use the Resource routes.

Comment: @francisco,  I added to my  RouteServiceProvider::boot() method the following: Route::pattern('role', '[0-9]+'), but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: What's more: `POST http://localhost/my_api/public/api/v1/roles/` fails and rather acts like  GET on the same route. Correct usage is without trailing slash: `POST http://localhost/my_api/public/api/v1/roles/1`

Comment: For PUT method to work on the route url MUST have trailing slash: `PUT http://localhost/my_api/public/api/v1/roles/1/ `- works as expected.

Comment: That should not be the case with trailing slash, using api resources and this is not a problem i have occoured, must be something conflicting you have not included in the question.